# Why is the inner div trying to clear other divs?

Tags: html, css

****NEW UPDATED*** JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qKP2v/8/*

I have a very simple layout of two sidebars floated left and right respectively. In the middle is a `#maincontent` div that has a `#content` div within it. The reason for this is so that the main content on the page can stretch to fill the size of the browser resolution.

The problem I have is when I want to insert divs (`#rectanglebox1, #rectanglebox2, #rectanglebox3`) that clears left and right floats within my `#content` div. But the #rectanglebox divs are trying to clear the sidebars which doesn't make any sense to me. The #rectanglebox divs are within the `#content` area which has no float applied to it. So why is the #rectanglebox div being pushed below the sidebars?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">   
    <div id="maincontent">
        <div id="aside-left">
            <ul>
                <li>Link1</li>
                <li>Link2</li>
                <li>Link3</li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
        <div id="aside-right">
            <ul>
                <li>Link1</li>
                <li>Link2</li>
                <li>Link3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>       
        <div id="content">
            <div id="ataglance">
            <div id="rectanglebox1"><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p></div>
                        <div id="rectanglebox2"><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p></div>
                        <div id="rectanglebox3"><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p></div>
        </div> 
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    min-height:200px;
    border: 1px solid #F0F;
}
#aside-left {
    height: 400px; /* guess */
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #9C0;
}
#maincontent {
    border: 1px solid #9C0;
    width:100%;
}
#maincontent #content{
    margin:0 130px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#aside-right {
    height: 400px; /* guess */
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid #9C0;
}
#ataglance {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#rectanglebox1 {
    float:left;
    margin-top:5px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    width:200px;
}
#rectanglebox2 {
    float:left;
    margin-top:5px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    width:250px;
}
#rectanglebox3 {
    float:left;
    margin-top:5px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    width:300px;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly how [`clear`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control) works - this is stated clearly in the spec: *"This property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) **may not be adjacent to an earlier floating box.** The 'clear' property does not consider floats inside the element itself or in other block formatting contexts.*"

Comment: @Adrift how do I solve it in this situation so the rectanglebox div only clears within the #content div. It should align with the top of the #content div.

Comment: It's not aligning to the top of `#content` because you have 30px of margin - http://jsfiddle.net/qKP2v/5/

Comment: Even if I remove the 30px margin, the whole div is being pushed down below height of the two sidebars because of the float/clear issue.

Comment: Then remove `clear: both;` from `#rectanglebox`

Comment: @Adrift if I want to float my rectangle boxes within another div, I'm getting this problem... http://jsfiddle.net/qKP2v/8/

I need the #ataglance div to 'contain' the floated rectangle boxes. Is this possible at all?

Comment: You can use `overflow: hidden;` (or any value other than `visible`, depending on what you're after) to `#ataglance` - http://jsfiddle.net/qKP2v/9/

Comment: I hate to keep pestering you like this, but would you mind being kind enough to edit my JSFiddle to show me what you mean?

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/qKP2v/9

Comment: Wow, that's made my year. Thank you Adrift I really appreciate it. If you can put it as an answer then I will vote it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code it's working for me !

```
<div id="wrapper">   
    <div id="maincontent">
        <div id="aside-left">
            <ul>
                <li>Link1</li>
                <li>Link2</li>
                <li>Link3</li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
        <div id="aside-right">
            <ul>
                <li>Link1</li>
                <li>Link2</li>
                <li>Link3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>       
        <div id="content">
            <div id="rectanglebox"><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur</p></div>
             <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>  
       <!-- <div style="clear:both;"></div>  no need for this -->
    </div>

</div>
```

and modify your css :

```
#rectanglebox {
    margin-top:30px;
    border: 1px solid orange;  
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: @2dar thank you for this answer. i have updated my JSFiddle to highlight the problem further here http://jsfiddle.net/qKP2v/6/

If I use your solution and float my rectangleboxes to the left, it would ruin the layout of the boxes. They should sit on top of each other, not next to each other.

Comment: in this case you have delete the float in rectanglebox1,2,3